# Road trip to Tromsø (polar circle) in late May: what tires?

Tags: driving, road-trips, norway

I’ve got my eye on a new epic adventure: driving up to Tromsø to see the midnight sun. I will probably start in Netherlands.

In my home country Netherlands, the weather is very pleasant in May. In fact, the weather is alright year round. I don’t even own winter tires for my car. That is a big contrast with Norway, especially north-Norway. I needed snow chains on my last trip there. That was in winter though. Winter tires aren’t useful over normal tires above 7 degrees, but they do work well in snowy conditions.

How are the roads to Tromsø in late May? Will summer tires be sufficient? Will I need to swap tires halfway the trip? If so, how do I judge where? Would all seasons be a better idea?

Please note: Yes, flying would be easier, but it wouldn’t be a road trip if I took the plane, right?

Comment: Weather in Tromsø [May 2018](https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/norway/tromso/historic?month=5&year=2018). No, you probably don't need winter tires.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would be fine with summer tires in May. We are not allowed to drive with studded tires after 1st of May if there is no snow/ice on the road, which is almost never is. https://www.vegvesen.no/om+statens+vegvesen/presse/nyheter/nasjonalt/piggdekk-og-sommerdekk

Comment: Studded tires are generally prohibited in the Netherland, in Germany and many other continental European countries.